# Can structured data how-to snippet be used to describe an action in software

Tags: google-search, structured-data

We added a step by step tutorials in our in-browser software.
And as we adding a pages for tutorials search and show tutorial details, I found the structured data How-To snippet/type.

I reviewed the snippet definition and guides and yet this is not clear enough on whether this can be used in our case (to describe a software-related how-to).

Comment: This question is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I am sorry for placing this question in my "default" StackOverflow questioning website, usually I have coding-related question. Is there a way to move the question to correct website of platform more or less "automatically"? (which one you would suggest? I just sorta unaware of SEO-dedicated site...